# Xpath with Two Conditions in Two Different Divs Selenium Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, xpath

Again trying to work on https://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/all/jackets. I want to be able to select products based on keywords I pass through but I want to figure out a way to do this better because Xpath brings me back the first black product that is black even if it does not match the first part of my find_element_by_xpath. I have tried nearly every other method of selecting things but this seems to be the best way to me as every other attribute is dynamic

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[text()[contains(.,'Raglan Court Jacket')]]") and driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[text()[contains(.,'Black')]]").click()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nice to see a fellow hypebeast here on StackOverflow, I've found a way to do this. By simply looping through elements and matching texts, using `enumerate` to get the next element and matching the text.

```
for index, element in enumerate(driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("a")):
    if element.text == "Raglan Court Jacket" and driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("a")[index + 1].text == "Black":
        element.click()
```

Comment: Same here. I appreciate the answer worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use this xpath:

```
//*[text()='Raglan Court Jacket']/parent::div/following-sibling::div/child::*[text()='Black']
```

Comment: this unfortunately threw up the no such element exception

Answer (score 0):

To select a black "Raglan Court Jacket", you can use :

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(.,'Raglan Court Jacket')][following-sibling::p[contains(.,'Black')]]/a").click()
```

Comment: problem was that it should've been following-sibling::div instead of ::p appreciate the help

Comment: OK. Thanks for the heads up.  Looks odd to me since "Black" is inside a p element located in the same div as the h1 element ("Raglan Court Jacket"). XPath tested OK with scrapy and rvest.